# AppFabric Cache - issue with Get

Tags: c#, appfabric

I have two client applications connecting to an Windows Server AppFabric Cluster (there is only one node). Client 1 Puts an object which has a datetime field to Cache (All entities are defined in a different C# class library project). When I **Get** this object through Client 1, everything looks good, however when I retrieve the same object through Client 2, I get the datetime field set to 01-01-0001 00:00:00 all the time. However, if I decorate the DateTime field with **[DataMember]** attribute, it works fine. Could someone please tell me what is going on?

Update: Client1 is a WCF service, and Client 2 is an ASP.NET application. Framework used is 4.0.

Comment: Can you show the class/field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppFabric serializes the type (using `NetDataContractSerializer`). If that type is decorated with `[DataContract]`, then only the members marked with `[DataMember]` will be serialized. If the type is not decorated with `[DataContract]`, then IIRC it defaults to `BinaryFormatter` behaviour, i.e. serializing the fields - it may or may not want `[Serializable]` in this case.

So: it sounds like the type is a data-contract so yes; you'll need to mark it `[DataMember]` - otherwise it will assume the all-zero value (`DateTime.MinValue`, aka 01-01-0001 00:00:00)